# Calculating improper integral $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> I want to calculate the improper integral $\displaystyle \int
>  \limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$
>   $\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}$

Therefore
\begin{align}
I(b)&=\lim\limits_{b\to0}\left(\displaystyle \int \limits_{b}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right) \qquad \forall b\in\mathbb{R}:0<b<\infty\\
&=\lim\limits_{b\to0}\left(\sqrt{\pi} \erf(\sqrt{b}) \right)=\sqrt{\pi}\erf(\sqrt{0})=\sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}

This looks way to easy. Is this correct or am I missing something? Do you know a better way while using the following equation from our lectures?: $$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: I corrected that, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

Just substitute $x= u^2$. So, you get
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x =2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du$$

Comment: Ok, so $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x =2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du =2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}=\sqrt{\pi}$ does the job?

Comment: Yes, it is the famous Gaussian integral.

Comment: @Doesbaddel : So ist es. :-)

Comment: You've switched from Gamma function to Gaussian integral. Why do you need it, if Gaussian integral is calculated through Gamma function

Comment: @YauhenMardan Because Doesbaddel asked exactly for something like this. Just read the post :-)

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: @Doesbaddel You are welcome.

Comment: @YauhenMardan In my studies, I saw the Gaussian integral first, and used it later to compute $\Gamma(1/2)$.

Answer (score 4):

It's the gamma function: $$\int_0^\infty x^{1/2-1}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}.$$

Comment: In particular $\Gamma^2(1/2)=\operatorname{B}(1/2,\,1/2)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}dx=\pi$, so we don't need to already know the Gaussian integral; in fact, this argument is one way to compute the Gaussian integral.